# Android app icon shorcut not launching activity

Tags: android, android-appshortcut

I'm trying to implement app icon shortcut on Android. I followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#static) but I'm having problem launching the app from the shortcut. Every time I click the app icon shortcut, nothing happens.
Here's the code on my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.package.myapp">

<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="${usesCleartextTraffic}"
    tools:ignore="ExportedService,GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>

    ...

</application>
</manifest>
```

Here's the `shortcuts.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:shortcutId="send_funds"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/LBL_SEND_FUNDS"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/BTN_SEND">

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.package.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.package.myapp" />
    </shortcut>

</shortcuts>
```

Comment: Hi. I'm curious how did you launch app with ```android:name``` attribute in application tag in your manifest? When I created simple project there is no such attribute, and when I tried to add it, Android Studio throws error: "Class was not found...".

Comment: You should add a class that extends Application class. Then set that class on application's  `android:name`. Check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was on the `buildType`. When running on `buildType`s other than the release build, I'm having the issue because the package name is different from what was indicated on the `android:targetPackage` of shortcut's intent. So what I did was, I created multiple `shortcuts.xml` with different `targetPackage` in the respective build folder:

```
app/src/debug/res/xml/shortcuts.xml
app/src/dev/res/xml/shortcuts.xml
app/src/staging/res/xml/shortcuts.xml
```

And set the `android:targetPackage` respectively:

```
android:targetPackage="com.package.myapp.debug"
android:targetPackage="com.package.myapp.dev"
android:targetPackage="com.package.myapp.staging"
```

Thanks to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361296/static-android-shortcuts-for-multiple-flavors) which is almost similar to my issue. And to [Rakesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51518675/3955965).